# Javascript runtime error $ is undefined?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I keep getting this annoying error pointing to my javascript function klm() and I have absolutely clueless why I get the error. I have checked my starting and closing tags and everything seems to look fine. What could I be doing wrong? The error specifically points to the klm method.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Dtata.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dtata" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function klm() {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Dtata.aspx/Hello",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: { name: 'hello' },
                  success: function (result) {
                      response(result.d);
                      Counter() 
                  },
                  error: function (result) {
                      alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                  }
              });
          }


          function Counter() {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "Dtata.aspx/Counter",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",

                  success: function (result) {
                      console.log(result.d);
                  },
                  error: function (result) {
                      alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                  }
              });
          }

           </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" onclick = "klm()" />
    <div>
    </div>



    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see the import of jQuery in your html page, like this: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: You need to include jQuery and the reason the error is pointing to your klm function and not your Counter one is because it's hitting the klm function first when loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery. Your script uses a jQuery function (`$.ajax()`) See: http://jquery.com/